# Solve for minimum x value in two-variable equation provided a ratio

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, ratio

The equation is:

$$500 = 5x - 2y$$

I know the ratio of x to y is $7:3$; what is the minimum possible value of x and how would I approach this question?

Comment: Looks to me there is only one solution to it. Copied the wrong problem?

Comment: The solution should be the intersection of two linear equations.  I see one solution.

Comment: @KittyL, it's not a problem from a book or anywhere really. It's for personal curiosity I guess? I haven't the foggiest of how to approach ratios like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up two equations $$500=5x-2y\\\frac{x}{y}=\frac{7}{3}\text{ or }y=\frac{3x}{7}$$

Knowing that $y=\frac{3x}{7}$, you can sub that into the other equation $$500=5x-2\frac{3x}{7}=5x-\frac{6}{7}x$$ and solve for x.